# Access principal from cookie middleware

Tags: asp.net, middleware, principal

I've succesfully setup an ASP.NET core application which use cookie middleware as detailed in [the docs.](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html)

Now I need to extract a claim from the authenticated Principal.
Quoting the above document:

> cookie middleware ... serializes a user principal into an encrypted cookie, and on subsequent requests, ... recreates the principal and assigns it to the User property on HttpContext.

But my **HttpContext.User is always null**.

Kestrel log shows

```
HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: myAuthScheme.
Authorization was successful for user: User1.
```

How can I retrieve Principal/Identity/Claim informations for the authenticated user?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: the issue was I was trying to access Controller.User inside the Controller constructor. This was too early. I had to move User checks inside the controller's actions.